# Resample time series based on different dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, pandas-resample

I have a table `df1` which consists of multiple time series represented by different `ID`. I want to resample the time series for each `ID` based on the start and end dates in another table `df2`. `df1` and `df2` are as below:

`df1:`

```
            Index       Timestamp               Data    ID
0           1           2010-03-04 13:16:44.310 125.0   1
4           6           2010-03-04 13:17:01.777 130.0   1   
5           7           2010-03-04 13:17:01.943 135.0   1   
12          16          2010-03-04 13:19:19.997 135.0   1   
16          21          2010-03-04 13:19:27.047 135.0   1   
... ... ... ... ... ...
45863344    45871285    2010-11-30 17:07:54.730 126.0   26  
45863345    45871286    2010-11-30 17:08:00.367 125.5   26  
45883410    45892266    2010-12-01 15:03:11.587 125.5   26  
45883411    45892267    2010-12-01 15:03:12.587 145.0   26  
45883619    45892475    2010-12-01 15:25:04.097 185.0   26
```

`df2:`

```
    End Date    Start Date    ID     Name  ...
0   2010-12-03  2010-11-23    1      AA01  ...
1   2010-04-07  2010-03-28    26     BB10  ...
    ... ... ... ... ... ...
```

I resampled the time series to have one date point per minute for a period of 10 days from `2010-01-01` to `2010-01-11` for each `ID`, which could be achieved with method below:

```
start = '2010-01-01'
end = '2010-01-11'

def f(x):
    r = pd.date_range(start=start, end = end, freq='1min')
    return x.reindex(r, method='ffill').bfill()


df_sub = (df1
        .set_index('Timestamp')
        .groupby('ID', sort=False)['Data']
        .apply(f)
        .rename_axis(['ID','Timestamp'])
        .reset_index()
        )
```

But this is based on the same start and end date of `2010-01-01` and `2010-01-11` for all `ID`. Is there a way to introduce different start and end date from `df2` for each `ID`, for example, for `ID 1` I only extract time series between `2010-11-23` and `2010-12-03`, and for `ID 26` only for time series between `2010-03-28` and `2010-04-07`?

The output would look like this:

```
        ID  Timestamp           Data
0       1   2010-12-03 00:00:00 125.5
1       1   2010-12-03 00:01:00 125.5
2       1   2010-12-03 00:02:00 185.5
3       1   2010-12-03 00:03:00 225.5
4       1   2010-12-03 00:04:00 215.5
... ... ... ... ...
2167409 26  2020-12-09 23:55:00 125.0
2167410 26  2010-12-09 23:56:00 135.0
2167411 26  2010-12-09 23:57:00 145.0
2167412 26  2010-12-09 23:58:00 125.0
... ... ... ... ...
```

Reproduciple example:
`df1:`

```
from pandas import Timestamp

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Index': {(2, 1): 2,
  (2, 6): 8,
  (2, 37): 47,
  (2, 81): 92,
  (2, 88): 101,
  (2, 132): 146,
  (2, 139): 155,
  (2, 436): 453,
  (2, 545): 564,
  (2, 816): 835,
  (10, 172): 188,
  (10, 450): 469,
  (10, 565): 584,
  (10, 830): 849,
  (10, 1000): 1019,
  (10, 271312): 271331,
  (10, 271313): 271332,
  (10, 271314): 271333,
  (10, 271315): 271334,
  (10, 271316): 271335,
  (120, 1614): 1633,
  (120, 1665): 1684,
  (120, 1666): 1685,
  (120, 1733): 1752,
  (120, 1734): 1753,
  (120, 1835): 1854,
  (120, 1836): 1855,
  (120, 1957): 1976,
  (120, 1958): 1977,
  (120, 2091): 2110},
 'Timestamp': {(2, 1): Timestamp('2014-03-04 13:16:44.310000'),
  (2, 6): Timestamp('2014-03-04 13:17:01.777000'),
  (2, 37): Timestamp('2014-04-17 11:59:57.470000'),
  (2, 81): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:01:08.973000'),
  (2, 88): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:05:55.153000'),
  (2, 132): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:08:58.933000'),
  (2, 139): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:35:58.290000'),
  (2, 436): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:41:42.147000'),
  (2, 545): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:46:14.450000'),
  (2, 816): Timestamp('2014-04-17 13:05:53.077000'),
  (10, 172): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:35:58.633000'),
  (10, 450): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:41:42.067000'),
  (10, 565): Timestamp('2014-04-17 12:46:14.747000'),
  (10, 830): Timestamp('2014-04-17 13:05:53.153000'),
  (10, 1000): Timestamp('2014-04-17 13:10:20.127000'),
  (10, 271312): Timestamp('2014-05-13 14:59:44.627000'),
  (10, 271313): Timestamp('2014-05-13 14:59:44.780000'),
  (10, 271314): Timestamp('2014-05-13 14:59:45.600000'),
  (10, 271315): Timestamp('2014-05-13 14:59:45.757000'),
  (10, 271316): Timestamp('2014-05-13 14:59:46.687000'),
  (120, 1614): Timestamp('2014-04-17 15:39:52.673000'),
  (120, 1665): Timestamp('2014-04-17 15:46:41.260000'),
  (120, 1666): Timestamp('2014-04-17 15:46:41.417000'),
  (120, 1733): Timestamp('2014-04-17 16:07:54.657000'),
  (120, 1734): Timestamp('2014-04-17 16:07:54.817000'),
  (120, 1835): Timestamp('2014-04-17 16:23:59.943000'),
  (120, 1836): Timestamp('2014-04-17 16:24:00.103000'),
  (120, 1957): Timestamp('2014-04-17 16:53:00.543000'),
  (120, 1958): Timestamp('2014-04-17 16:53:00.703000'),
  (120, 2091): Timestamp('2014-04-17 17:29:21.163000')},
 'Data': {(2, 1): 30.0,
  (2, 6): 30.0,
  (2, 37): 25.0,
  (2, 81): 25.0,
  (2, 88): 25.0,
  (2, 132): 25.0,
  (2, 139): 25.0,
  (2, 436): 25.0,
  (2, 545): 25.0,
  (2, 816): 25.0,
  (10, 172): 25.0,
  (10, 450): 25.0,
  (10, 565): 25.0,
  (10, 830): 25.0,
  (10, 1000): 25.0,
  (10, 271312): 25.0,
  (10, 271313): 27.5,
  (10, 271314): 27.5,
  (10, 271315): 30.5,
  (10, 271316): 30.5,
  (120, 1614): 31.0,
  (120, 1665): 30.5,
  (120, 1666): 30.0,
  (120, 1733): 29.5,
  (120, 1734): 29.0,
  (120, 1835): 28.5,
  (120, 1836): 28.0,
  (120, 1957): 27.5,
  (120, 1958): 27.0,
  (120, 2091): 26.5},
 'ID': {(2, 1): 2,
  (2, 6): 2,
  (2, 37): 2,
  (2, 81): 2,
  (2, 88): 2,
  (2, 132): 2,
  (2, 139): 2,
  (2, 436): 2,
  (2, 545): 2,
  (2, 816): 2,
  (10, 172): 10,
  (10, 450): 10,
  (10, 565): 10,
  (10, 830): 10,
  (10, 1000): 10,
  (10, 271312): 10,
  (10, 271313): 10,
  (10, 271314): 10,
  (10, 271315): 10,
  (10, 271316): 10,
  (120, 1614): 120,
  (120, 1665): 120,
  (120, 1666): 120,
  (120, 1733): 120,
  (120, 1734): 120,
  (120, 1835): 120,
  (120, 1836): 120,
  (120, 1957): 120,
  (120, 1958): 120,
  (120, 2091): 120}
  })
```

`df2:`

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': {8: 10, 9: 2, 116: 120},
 'Start Date': {8: Timestamp('2014-04-20 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2014-03-04 00:00:00'),
  116: Timestamp('2014-04-17 00:00:00')},
 'End Date': {8: Timestamp('2014-04-30 00:00:00'),
  9: Timestamp('2014-03-14 00:00:00'),
  116: Timestamp('2014-04-27 00:00:00')},
 'comment': {8: 'TBA', 9: 'TBA', 116: 'TBA'},
 'Name': {8: 'NN95', 9: 'AA01', 116: 'BB10'}})

df2
```

Comment: can you share code to generate example input data so we can help you develop a solution?

Comment: Hi @erap129, please see edited question for example data. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work. Just join `df1` and `df2` to obtain the start and end dates for each `ID`. Tell me if I missed the point.

```
def f(sub_df):
    r = pd.date_range(start=sub_df['Start Date'].iloc[0], end=sub_df['End Date'].iloc[0], freq='1min')
    return sub_df.reindex(r, method='ffill').bfill()['Data']


df_sub = (pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID')
        .set_index('Timestamp')
        .groupby('ID', sort=False)
        .apply(f)
        .rename_axis(['ID','Timestamp'])
        .reset_index()
        )
```

Edit: Use the approach below if the same `ID` in `df2` can be associated with multiple start-date, end-date pairs:

```
def f(sub_df):
    r = pd.date_range(start=sub_df['Start Date'].iloc[0], end=sub_df['End Date'].iloc[0], freq='1min')
    return sub_df.reindex(r, method='ffill').bfill()['Data']

df2['group_id'] = df2.index

df_sub = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID').\
    set_index('Timestamp').\
    groupby(['ID', 'group_id'], sort=False).\
    apply(f).\
    rename_axis(['ID', 'group_id', 'Timestamp']).\
    reset_index().drop(columns=['group_id'])
```

Comment: Hey erap129, this works perfectly! I do have one question - why do we need `.iloc[0]` in `sub_df['Start Date'].iloc[0]` for the start and end date extraction in `f`?

Comment: because I merged `df1` and `df2` so each measurement contains the start and end dates. It means there is redundant data in the merged dataframe but I think it simplifies things because we can perform all of the operations on a single dataframe.

Comment: Hey erap129, just realised another issue - there might be duplicates of `ID` but with different start and end dates. I tried to use `groupby(['ID','Timestamp'])` in `df_sub` but encountered error `ValueError: Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex.`

Comment: Also, it seems it's not picking up all data as compared to an alternative method using for-loop.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean regarding duplicates if `ID` with different start and end dates. I would, in this case, use the index of `df2` as the grouping value. This way you allow duplicate date ranges for the same `ID`, see my edited answer. Regarding "not picking up all data points compared to an alternative method using for-loop", can you give an example?